# Filling blanks (missing values) in table with value above using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, table

I'm using ArcMap to tidy up some field collected point data. The point data is a sequential track from a handheld device. In the attribute table i have a field with differant activities that separate out each track. However, only  the first occurrence/point of the activity is filled in and the rest below are blank till the next activity. .eg.

### running

### -

### walking

### -

Is there a way to filldown the entries to blank fields below? There are hundreds of blank entries for each one with a value, not sure if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming this structure:

[image]

create new field and run this field calculator expression on it:

```
def fillMe(text):
 global before
 if text=="-":
  return before
 else:
  before=text
  return before
```

## -----------------------

```
fillMe( !CAT_DOG!)
```

[image]

Comment: This expression can be reduced by 2 lines by using <> in if statement. Current structure makes it easier to read

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "global before" ? Is the "before" item something dependent on the order of the FID field or can it be affected by the current order of the table ? To explain in an other way : if the table was ordered differently, would it change the way your code would work ?

Comment: I believe arcgis works using physical records position, I.e. using FID

Comment: Have you read OP at all? My answer tailored to it. Feel free to post your own

Comment: Op is original post, question. It states an order of features and no mentioning of other fields. Thus no way to apply sorting

Comment: OK,I see what you mean. I missed the "sequential track" info. In this case, no problem. I'm deleting my previous comments.